# Google Analytics Integration in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

Im trying to integrate Google Analytics in SWIFT. I used this [user guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/) and tried to do in SWIFt. But I'm having hard time since this is the first time using Google Analytics. Is there any tutorial/resource for SWIFT ? Thanks in advance.

Edit1: Procedure and code I have used,
1. Added the google headers in bridging-header file
2. Added these in Appdelegate

```
 GAI.sharedInstance().trackUncaughtExceptions = true
 GAI.sharedInstance().dispatchInterval = 20
 GAI.sharedInstance().trackerWithTrackingId("UA-XXXX-YY")
```

3. Gave the screen name in viewDidAppear as `self.screenName = "Game Screen"`
4. Created an event as

```
var tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().trackerWithTrackingId("UA-XXXX-YY")
tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory("SolveGame", action: "GameSolved", label: "Solve", value: nil).build())
```

Comment: have u show ur code what u tried , it is easy to optimize the answer

Comment: ya your coding is fine  for event tracking and automatic tracking , k now what the problem u faced and what the help u need'

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Happy if the code is looking fine. Here I don't get the screen/events recorded in Real Time.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Also I'm getting this error in the GA website "Property <App Name> is not receiving hits. Either your site is not receiving any sessions or it is not tagged correctly."

Comment: u tried the GA for website

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late, but I was in a similar situation today - not knowing much about Google Analytics and trying to implement it in Swift, for which there's little help online yet.  I got it working with basically the same code you have shown here.  One suggestion:  If you also set

```
GAI.sharedInstance().logger.logLevel = GAILogLevel.Verbose
```

You may get some useful messaging in the console.

One other minor point is that I'm calling `trackerWithTrackingId()` first, before the other calls.  Not sure if order matters.

Also, I'm assuming from your point #3 that you're implementing `GAITrackedViewController`, but figured I would mention that anyway as a tip.

And one final sanity check - you are using your actual tracking id, rather than `"UA-XXXX-YY"` in your code, right?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to deal with this. I used both the demo provided AND integrated it into my app.

Nothing. 0s.

Then I came in this morning to take a look. It was working this morning. So evidently there is a good bit of lag before this aspect of Google Analytics kicks in.

---

As for your event tracking, that should work if you are tracking events, however that isn't how you would track a given page.

Assuming that want to track pages to you would want to use something like this.

```
var storyboardViewName = "Lender-Details-View"

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // [START GOOGLE ANALYTICS]
        var tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
        tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: storyboardViewName)
        var builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView()
        tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
        // [END GOOGLE ANALYTICS]
//.... other code here .....

}
```

Comment: Check sample app @ https://github.com/phanisai4u/sampleAppsSwift/tree/master/GoogleAnalyticsSampleSwift